# yii image doesn't display

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using Yii 2.0 (Advanced Yii 2.0 Application Structure) and I am pretty newbie. Before reading a lot of documentation I think this should be the 'best practised' way of publishing-showing an image.

```
$path = Yii::$app->basePath.'/views/images';
$assets_url = Yii::$app->assetManager->publish($path).'/';
$video_explicativo = $assets_url."video_explicativo.jpg";
echo "<img id='video_explicativo' src='$video_explicativo' />";
```

But it doesn't work. 
Image file is copied successfuly from frontend/views/images/video_explicativo.jpg to frontend/web/assets/81a22c66/video_explicativo.jpg, but $assets_url is returning an array, instead of a string with the URL. So the image doesn't display.

Can you help me with this?
I beg you pardon for my poor english.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
$path = Yii::$app->basePath.'/views/images';
$assets_url = Yii::$app->assetManager->publish($path);
$video_explicativo = $assets_url[1].'/'."video_explicativo.jpg";
echo "<img id='video_explicativo' src='$video_explicativo' />";
```

As, `$assets_url` is an array which `$assets_url[0]` is the asset path and `$assets_url[1]` is the asset url.

Comment: I tested it before unsuccessfuly, but your change of '/' from line 2 to line 3 was the key. A lot of thanks, Ali.